# Selective Desaturation as picture effect

Tags: android

I am working on image processing app for android!! and I have to do some picture effect like "selective Desaturation" Does any body know how this works?

Can you help me with the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this library:
http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html